# Let $x$ be an involution in a finite group $G$ and $K$ be a component of $C_G(x)$. Show that $K\subseteq E(G)$ or $[C_{E(G)}(x),K]=1$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, involutions

> Let $x$ be an involution in a finite group $G$ and $K$ be a component of $C_G(x)$. Show that $K\subseteq E(G)$ or $[C_{E(G)}(x),K]=1$.

Here, $E(G)$ is the layer of the group $G$.

**My attempt:** Suppose $E(G)\subseteq C_G(t)$. Then $C_{E(G)}(x)=E(G)$. Now, $K$ is a component of $C_G(x)$ and $E(G)$ is a subnormal subgroup of $C_G(x)$, so $K\subseteq E(G)$ or $[K,C_{E(G)}(x)]=1$, and we're done.

---

I don't know how to handle the general case, specially where to use the fact that $t$ is an involution?

---

**Edit:** I think the argument is as follows: Since $E(G)$  is a normal subgroup of $G$, so $C_{E(G)}(x)=E(G)\cap C_G(x)$ is a normal subgroup of $C_G(x)$. Combining with the fact that $K$ is a component of $C_G(x)$, we get that $K\subseteq C_{E(G)}(x)\subseteq E(G)$ or $[K,C_{E(G)}(x)]=1$.

Comment: $x$ or $t$? Are they the same?

Comment: Yes, sorry. $\,\,\,\,\,$

Comment: I might be only one, but I don't know what  "component" and "layer" mean here.

Comment: [Component](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_%28group_theory%29). [Layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitting_subgroup#The_generalized_Fitting_subgroup).

Comment: *Hint*: $[C_{E(G)}(x),K] \le E(G) \cap E(C_G(x))$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Can you check my edit?

Comment: But you haven't proved anything, you have just stated that the result follows.

Comment: $C_{E(G)}(x)$ acting by conjugation permutes the components of $C_G(x)$. If it does not normalize $K$, then $K \le [C_{E(G)}(x),K]$. If it normalizes $K$ then either $K \le [C_{E(G)}(x),K]$ or $[C_{E(G)}(x),K] \le Z(K)$. In the second case, the three subgroups lemma and the fact that $K$ is perfect imply $[C_{E(G)}(x),K]=1$.

Comment: @DerekHolt I have used the result that if $K$ is a component of a group $H$ and $N$ is a normal subgroup of $H$, then either $K\subseteq N$ or $[K,N]=1$. Here, $H=C_G(x)$ and $N=C_{E(G)}(x)$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Am I correct?